# How to receive and return a string type using a Delphi DLL in C#

Tags: c#, delphi, dll

Is it possible to use strings? I read that it is necessary to use Pchar but couldn't find a way to make it work. 
Here is the DLL code:

```
function DeCrypt( Mensagem: String;): String; export; StdCall;
var
P,
Q: Array[1..2] of string;
i: integer;


begin

{Blocos criptografados}
P[1] :=  Copy(Mensagem,7,2) + Copy(Mensagem,12,2);
P[2] :=  Copy(Mensagem,8,4) + Copy(Mensagem,29,3);
for i:= 1 to 2 do
  Q[i] := Decodifica(P[i]);

Result  := Copy(Mensagem,1,19) +
           Copy(Q[1],5,2) + Copy(Q[2],5,2) + Copy(Q[3],5,2) + '000' +
           Copy(Q[1],2,3) + Copy(Q[2],2,3) + Copy(Q[3],2,3);

end;

exports DeCrypt;
```

Here is my C# code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string aux = textBox1.Text;
        string aux2 = "";

        aux2 = DeCrypt(aux);
    }

        textBox2.Text = aux2;
    }
```

Comment: No, it is not possible. Delphi strings don't have any equivalent in any other programming language. There are endless examples out there covering the proper way though.

Comment: I have almost zero knowledge in delphi and its been difficult to find any proper way to do it, do you have any example or can tell where I could find one that work?

Comment: This has been covered many many times here. A bit of research will be rewarding. You'll want to pass in a character array allocated by the caller that the callee populates. That's best done with StringBuilder in the C# side. You will use PAnsiChar on the Delphi side. But websearch will reveal all. Then again, if you have zero delphi knowledge you aren't going to succeed. And it's not our place to write your code for you. You need to manage your expectations and be prepared to learn enough delphi to be able to tackle the problem. Don't imagine there are magic shortcuts to knowledge.

Comment: Also, in any case, no matter what type you use, it can't be used as the function result. Should be a `var` parameter instead.

Comment: @jerry No. It should not be a var parameter. Two PAnsiChar parameters are needed. Both allocated by caller. One whose content is read by callee, the other written to.

Comment: @David Indeed, but doesn't it have to be `var` or `out` to be written to?

Comment: @Jerry No. PAnsiChar is a pointer. The address of a character array. The pointer is passed by value and the data is written to that address.